# Properties of Landau symbols

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am just looking for some clarification of some of the properties of Landau symbols. I know and understand the following multiplicative properties:

$f(x)O(1)=O(f(x))$

$O(f(x))O(1)=O(f(x))$

$O(f(x))O(g(x))=O(f(x)g(x))$

And so on. However, what is the rule of thumb when it comes to addition of these Landau symbols? For example:

$O(x)+O(1) \stackrel{?}{=} O(x)$

$O(f(x))+O(g(x)) \stackrel{?}{=} \max\{O(f(x),O(g(x))\}$

$O\Big(\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\Big)+O\big(\frac{1}{x}\big) \stackrel{?}{=} O\Big(\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\Big)$

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the second property that you don't understand:

Consider for example $x^3+x^2$ where $x \geq 1$.

Doesn't it hold that $x^3+x^2 \leq x^3+x^3=2x^3$?